# Get transaction details using transaction ID - Paypal

Tags: php, api, paypal

What I am trying to do is I would like to verify transaction ID of Paypal payments. But paypal sends me back a:

```
{"name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","message":"Requested resource ID was not found.","information_link":"https:\/\/developer.paypal.com\/docs\/api\/payments\/#errors"}
```

my current code right now is this:

```
$curl = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/<transaction_id>");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . '<changed this to my access token>',
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$result = json_decode($response);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong endpoint of Paypal API. Based on your description of what you want to do, you should be using /v1/checkout/orders/ as per the documentation because it gives you all the details of a certain transaction.

Do it like this:

```
$curl = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/checkout/orders/<transaction_id>");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . '<access_token>',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$result = json_decode($response);
```

Source: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v1/

Comment: Thanks for this mate. This did really solved my problem.

Comment: Still it gives me the same error. Im using sandbox and generate token with sanbox only.